# Can someone explain me why I am getting two different answers for the below codes?

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 2, y = 0;
    int m = (y |= 10);
    int z = y && m;
    printf("%d\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

Above program gives me output as 1. Below code is giving me output 0 but what is the reason for different outputs here?

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    int x = 2, y = 0;
    int z = y && (y |= 10);
    printf("%d\n", z);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `y && (y |= 10)` is 0 when `y == 0` so `z == 0` in the second case

Comment: what makes you think that `(y |= 10)` executes first? it executes only if the first part is non-zero. That's the principle of short circuiting

Answer (score 1):

In

```
int z = (y |= 10);
```

`y` is masked with `10` so set to `10`, so `y && m` is a boolean worth `1` because both `y` and `m` are non-zero, assigned to `z`

Now, in

```
int z = y && (y |= 10);
```

`y == 0` so `&&` *short-circuits*, not evaluating the right hand part and not changing the value of `y`. Therefore, `z` is set to 0.

Had you used:

```
int z = y & (y |= 10);
```

this would have depended on how/in which order the compiler evaluates the operands (implementation defined behaviour to get `0` or `10`)

note that `&&` short-circuiting doesn't evaluate the second parameter if the first is zero *for a very good reason*:

```
if ((pointer != NULL) && pointer->value == 12) { do_something(); }
```

this condition checks if the value is 12 but *only* if the pointer is non-NULL. If the second expression was evaluated first, this could crash.